# Cannot create object for DataGridBoolColumn in winform for datagrid in windows ce 6 app

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, windows-phone, windows-ce

I am trying to create an object of DataGridBoolColumn. But it is not in any namespace. Below is my simple code.

> The type or namespace name 'DataGridBoolColumn' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)   C:\Csharp
>   apps\PickerPayScreener\PickerPayScreener\Form1.cs 235 21  PickerPayScreener

I am getting a red squiggle line under DataGridBoolColumn.

```
DataGridBoolColumn cs1 = new DataGridBoolColumn();
cs1.NullValue = false;
cs1.TrueValue = true;
cs1.FalseValue = false;
cs1.MappingName = "checked";
cs1.ReadOnly = false;
gdPickerDetail.TableStyles[0].GridColumnStyles.Add(cs1);
```

Comment: can you show your DataGridBoolColumn  class?

Comment: I dont have one. Do I need to create one?

Comment: is DataGridBoolColumn in some dll then?? or it is your own class??

Comment: it should be in  using System.Windows.Forms; thats what I think. But I could nor get it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DataGridBoolColumn` isn't supported in the .NET Compact Framework (used in Windows CE). See the MSDN page: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172499(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try placing the below code at the start of your source code (.cs) file

```
 using System.Windows.Forms;
```

Also make sure that your project references the assembly `System.Windows.Forms.dll`.

Comment: I am using System.Windows.Forms;. I am using C# 3.0 framework 3.5

Comment: This should work.  What is the exact error when you compile?

Comment: the exception is: The type or namespace name 'DataGridBoolColumn' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Csharp apps\PickerPayScreener\PickerPayScreener\Form1.cs 235 21 PickerPayScreener

Comment: What is Error 1.  I think you are referencing the dll.

Answer (score 0):

Try System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn Instead